# Pushing Local repository to remote in Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have maintained my source code in my local repository till date that includes all the detailed history including tags information. Now that a place in the Bitbucket server space is created for our project, I need to push all the source code from my machine (local repository) to the remote repository location reserved for us.

**Location:**
https://bitbucket.companyname.com/projects/
here are subfolders in this location. Inside which I need to push my local repository.

When I navigate to that specific page Bitbucket

[image]

I use the 3rd. option since my code is already tracked by Git.

However, when I execute the following command

cd existing-project-directory

git remote set-url origin https://@bitbucket.companyname.com/scm/notfr/its_upgrade_tool.git

git push -u origin master

***existing-project-directory***:  Directory containing sources and history information including the tags.

I get a fatal error: no such repository exists

My question is should I have to specifically create a separate remote repository in the remote location before pushing my local changes?. If I do that will it not overwrite the version history information.?

Comment: Have you tried using `ssh:` for the remote URL?

Comment: I have generated the ssh keys. But how is this related

Comment: You set the remote URL to `https:…`. Have you tried `ssh:…` (like the example shows)? I don't think you'll be able to push over HTTP.

Comment: Hey this worked :). Please include this as an answer for me to accept it

Comment: I'd feel silly writing an answer that just says ‘do what the example says’. IMO this question should be closed for being such a minor error.

Comment: Stop being modest :). I should feel silly instead for missing such a basic requirement.